# How I can use the Webinterface by Loginventory in IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: asp.net, iis, mime-types, windows-server-2012

hi we use the software Loginventory and this have a webinterface for IIS. I install the application and want to connect to this default.aspx but then I get this message:

[image]

Here is my Configuration: Authentifizierung

[image]

Here is the delegation:

[image]

I dont understand what I must do that it works -.-

thanks for every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "Web Server/Application Development/Asp.net 4.5" feature to your Windows 2012 server via the Add Roles and Features Wizard.

The Features ".NET Extensibility 4.5, ISAPI Extensions and ISAPI Filters" should be selected as well.

Also consider to disable "anonymous access" and enable "Windows Authentication" to restrict access.